# Bundle SharePoint JavaScript files inside SharePoint hosted app

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-hosted-app

We have a SharePoint hosted app. This app require some scripts from SharePoint; **MicrosoftAjax.js**, **init.js**, **sp.runtime.js**, **sp.js**, **sp.taxonomy.js** and **sp.workflowservices.js**.
We load all these from **/_layouts/15/**, except for **MicrosoftAjax** which we load from **ajax.aspnetcdn.com**.

What we are thinking about is to bundle all these files into our **app.js**. We use gulp to build our app, so we only have one file, except for the files above.
Problems I can think of:

1. How can we detect changes in the built in scripts?
2. Are there differences between on-premise and SharePoint online?
3. Are any parts of the scripts dynamic (variables set when requesting the scritps)?

We had problems with MicrosoftAjax.js, once it was removed from 15 hive, and once the DNS did not resolve.

Comment: So you are trying to replace SharePoints [SOD](http://www.migee.com/2015/09/24/understanding-sharepoint-and-script-on-demand-sod/) with your own?

Comment: @DannyEngelman We simply don't use any dynamic loading. Our app has a very light weight `index.html` page, and we don't need to load anything on demand or asynchronously.

Comment: From a Governance point of view I would not accept any add-ins that replaces default Microsoft scripts with their own. Your add-in is payload and if it changes anything in the trucks engine I can imagine Microsoft won't give support either.

Comment: @DannyEngelman The scripts are only client side scripts, libraries that can be changed externally in any case, be it be re-evaluating or overriding the prototype. The `app.js`-file is in any case bundled with the app, so it can not be changed after deploy, which in theory makes it safer than pointing to built in scripts which can be changed, even by third party be it on-premise.

Comment: OnPrem could vary iguess, depending on patch/service pack they run.  Some function in the init.js on O365 uses _spPageContextInfo.userId etc, that is not available onprem (on my version of 2013).

Comment: @AndersAune I didn't know that `_spPageContextInfo` is used, that is kind of bad for us. However everything works so far, on both O365, and on-premise 2013 (several versions) and 2016. Our index [looks like this](https://gist.github.com/eirikb/5cd08a357f5aab8b0911).

Comment: @eirikb I have only seen it in there, not sure if there is some fail safes etc, or if you even will use the functions where it is used.

Comment: @eirikb btw, the global variable; g_all_modules shows the current version of all loaded SP scripts. You could probably build something to look for changes in those versions numbers if you are looking for something to detect changes in the built in scripts. I recon they are strict with changing the numbers when they do any changes.

Comment: @AndersAune Nice. Thanks. I'm currently leaning against keeping the setup I have. But I don not trust the location of MicrosoftAjax, be it the hive or the cdn, so that file I will bundle with my app (separately from my app.js)

Comment: Note: I have been testing bundling JSPM with webpack, and it works without problems, but until webpack2 get their tree-shaking fixed the file size will be humongous (1.15MB uglified, 164KB with gzip).

Answer (score 0):

You're bundling everything that comes with Microsoft SharePoint into your own js file. This could lead into the typical problem, which is your first question, you can't never detect changes in the built-in scripts.

Unless if you use RPA or PowerShell to frequently download those scripts and compare, re-bundle the script if needed and republish whatever customization you're trying to do.

Even when the evidence proof that bundling those scripts works both on-premises and SPO, I would still avoid doing so.

**Yes, there are differences between on-premises and SPO**. Even with the most frequent updates installed or if you're using subscription model, SharePoint on-premises is always behind, while SharePoint Online is always ahead of updates and features. That's practically how Microsoft sells SharePoint Online.

"Are any parts of the scripts dynamic (variables set when requesting the scritps)?" - I have no idea on this.